# How many times do I need to draw $X$ items from a set on $N$ items to get a probability $P$ that each item is selected at least $K$ times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424493/how-many-times-i-need-to-draw-k-items-from-a-list-of-n-items-to-get-a-probabilit) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30483/probability-of-selecting-each-item-at-least-once-when-sampling-with-replacement) are some related (but slightly different) questions. My question is more general.

I have a set of $N$ elements. I want to repeatedly draw $X$ items ($X \le N$) with replacement, i.e. I first choose $X$ items without replacement and then I replace them in the original set. I want each element to be drawn at least $K$ times. So how many times do I have to draw $X$ elements such that I have probability $P$ that each element has been drawn at least $K$ times?

Let's do an example. I have a deck of $N=10$ cards, labeled $1, 2, ..., 10$. At each step I draw $X=3$ cards, I look at them and then I put them back in the deck. How many times do I have to perform such step in order to draw each single card at least $K=5$ times with probability $P=0.95$?